# Best practice to encrypt and decrypt passwords between services

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa

So basically I'm developing a service that requires plain text input of user and password from the user.

The main server won't ever need to decrypt the password, so it should encrypt the user password with the public key and store it to DB.

Consuming service, which does web scraping needs the password as plain text to be able to authenticate. 
And uses a private key for decryption.

I'm wondering whats the best practice to store the cert, I tried to base64 encrypt the key and use it from env. But something is getting corrupted at times. And being unable to decrypt the password.

Any advice on how to handle it is helpful

Comment: Why don't you do it the same way everybody else does it? username/password over https.

Comment: it's backend service, and these passwords need to be stored in DB, but I don't like the idea of storing it as plain text

Comment: My apologies, Martin, I'm kind of slow at understanding these things. I'm confused about which piece is doing what thing. If the password is from a user, then why not just use the password when the user types it in?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't worry so much about obfuscating the key.  Just make sure the server its on is secured, and limit access to the key via permissions and users which have access to that account.  If it were a service account with no login ability, that would be better.  If you need to reproduce this concept multiple times, use different key/cert for each unique use of this process to limit the exposure if there is a compromise.  I'm sure there will be more good responses... let them stack up and see which mix best suits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice it to hash passwords and store the hashes. When a user logs in, hash their input and compare its value to the hash you already have stored. In this manner a compromise only reveals the hashes, not the actual passwords. There are rainbow tables to crack hashes, but that's a topic for another day.